# .htaccess RewriteRule with two or more vars and special delimiter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have URLs structure like this:

http://domain.com/en/test/?page=2
http://domain.com/smth/en/test/;sysmod/dashboard/?page=2

and I want to rewrite URLs like that:

http://domain.com/?var1=en/test/?page=2
http://domain.com/?var1=smth/en/test/&var2=sysmod/dashboard/?page=2

as I want to use $_GET method in php scripts for var1 and var2 variables.

My own htaccess code looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*);(.*)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,QSA]<br/>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This looks to be working but...css or js script arent loaded in page even if add 
`RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}`
for css/js folder.

Thank You!

Comment: You are probably using relative links. Use absolute paths for CSS and js and you shouldn't have problems.

Comment: I use http://domain.com/css_dir/css_file.css links for css/js files but this doesn't make any good.

Comment: try putting `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` before each rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Panama Jack,

but I've got working it couple of minutes ago. What I did:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*);(.*)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]
```